# Preventing Entity Framework from serializing EntityKey, EntitySetName, etc

Tags: entity-framework, serialization

I have a webservice that retuns entity framework objects. On the calling side, I don't do anything but read the information, so I don't need these entity framework serialization attributes.  Is it possible to remove the following serialized text when returning entity framework objects?

```
<EntityKey> <EntitySetName>ClassName</EntitySetName> <EntityContainerName>MyEntities</EntityContainerName> -<EntityKeyValues> -<EntityKeyMember> <Key>ClassID</Key> <Value xsi:type="xsd:int">9903</Value> </EntityKeyMember> </EntityKeyValues> </EntityKey>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've read up on how EF would require me to make a bunch of POCOs and such, which required me to do a lot of work.  I decided to think about it some more and did some digging on the Entity object.  After seeing that it wasn't sealed, I created a custom class that inherits from this class and added a 'new' statement to the EntityKey field with the XmlIgnore attribute.  Going back to my EF designer class, I changed all classes to inherit from CustomEntityObject instead and voila!, no unneccessary fields.  Whether this is future proof, I doubt it.  But for this project, it works great and it didn't require me to write DTOs for all my classes.  Hopefully someone else finds it useful:

```
public class CustomEntityObject : EntityObject {
    [DataMember]
    [Browsable(false)]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public new EntityKey EntityKey { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does not survive updating the schema from the server, but easily refixed.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is not possible. If you use `EntityObject` base entities you will always have this data in web service result. If you don't want to expose them you must either use DTO (custom objects which will transfer only data you want) or you must use EFv4 and POCOs which do not contain `EntityKey` and other EF related properties.